# Stochastic dynamics: how do the random matrix $J_{ij}$ and coupling strengh $g$ affect the variance of the local field $h_i$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-differential-equations

*Context: Q3 in [How to understand the largest Lyapunov exponent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4451013/577710)*

> [image: fig9]

We know $g$ is proportional to (square root of) the variance of $J$'s every entry ($J_{ij}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,g^2/N)$).
Why is it also positively related to the variance of $h_i$.
In other words, why stronger coupling results in stronger neuronal signals, from a math perspective, in particular, for large systems?

---

*Clarification of notations in the paper [(Crisanti, 2018)](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.98.062120)*:

$S_i^a=\phi (gh^a_i)=\phi (g h_i(t_a))$ ($a,b,c,d$ are indexes for time), i.e. $S$ is the signal/output of neuron.

$C_{ab}=\sum \limits _iS_aS_b/N $, i.e. $C$ is autocorrelation of neuronal signals at times $t_a,t_b$. (I think $\sum \limits _iS_aS_b=\sum \limits _i(S_a-\langle S_a\rangle )(S_b-\langle S_b\rangle )$, since the averages of $S_a,S_b$ are both $0$, for the neuronal signals are random centered at zero.)

---

*Noteworthy details (Crisanti, 2018):*

> If the matrix $J_{ij}$ is symmetric, i.e., $J_{ji}=J_{ij}$, [...] The dynamics hence converges toward stable fixed points.
> If the matrix is nonsymmetric, [...] a richer steady-state behavior emerges: besides fixed points, limit cycles and chaotic behavior are also possible.
>
>
> The assumption of zero average implies that there is not a preferred type of synaptic connection... inhibitory ($N\overline J_{ij}<0$) or excitatory ($N\overline J_{ij}>0$).
>
>
> [image: fig0]
>
>
> [image: fig00]
>
>
> [image: fig1]
>
>
> [image: fig2]

---

*General questions*: The paper (Crisanti, 2018) is not easy for me. While I do not expect others to read the paper for me, how could I understand a paper like this? For example, what step should I follow, what prerequisite knowledge should I familiarize myself with?

---

*Brief summary of topics and methods*: The paper (Crisanti, 2018) uses some stochastic diff eq (SDE)/Ito (part of SD), functional, Fourier transform, etc.
The research seems to be within the domain of  **stochastic dynamics (SD)** in statistical mechanics. The author here adopts a frequently used path integral method; while I am not familiar with the method, it seems to be about variational methods, which consider a functional (typically an integral; the author mentions 'action') and a small variation $\delta$, introduced to eq6 (Crisanti, 2018)(?) and resulting in a stochastic diff eq.

---

*General background*: The following is an excerpt from a paper (Weinan E, 2000) about stochastic PDEs in hydrodynamic chaos, which seems to be relevant to the above problem of **chaos in neural networks**.

> [image: fig3]

---

*Specific questions*: When $J_{ij}$ is symmetric, there is an energy function (eq 3)(Crisanti, 2018), while when $J_{ij}$ is asymmetric, there is not, why? And why is the energy function in the form of eq3, and its relaxation in the form of eq2 (Crisanti, 2018)?

---

**References**:
A. Crisanti and H. Sompolinsky, *Path integral approach to random neural networks*, 2018 https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.98.062120 this is what is cited by the original paper (excerpted in [the previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4451013/577710)) about $g$, $h_i$, and *where most of the excerpts above come from*.

H. Sompolinsky, A. Crisanti, and H. J. Sommers, *Chaos in Random Neural Networks*, 1988 https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.61.259 this is a paper that gives solution to the nonlinear ODEs.

Weinan E, *Stochastic PDEs in Turbulence Theory*, 2000

NIPS 2006 Workshop on
*Dynamical Systems, Stochastic Processes and Bayesian Inference* [www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.archambeau/dsb.htm](https://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.archambeau/dsb.htm) 
*Path Integral Method for Estimation of Time Series* [www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.archambeau/accepts/restrepo.pdf](https://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.archambeau/accepts/restrepo.pdf)

Comment: Here is a question [How to understand the Ising model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711267/273056) relates solid state physics and neural system models. // It may help those unfamiliar with computational neuroscience understand the context of the neural network model--which is similar to the **Ising model/MFT** in condensed matter physics.